# the google chrome devtools reqeust type filter disappear in macos

Tags: google-chrome

Today when I open the google chrome devtools `Version 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (arm64)` and did not found the http reqeust type filter:

[image]

what should I do to make the request type filter show? the result may look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to click the red filter icon

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bitar.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).